# Modify polyline

Tags: fabricjs

If I want to add an extra line to an existing polyline, should I remove this existing polyline from the canvas first, modify the points matrix, and add the new polyline? Or is it possible to change the existing polyline, like changing the text of a text object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may remove whole polyline and add a new one or else you need to calculate the dimensions(left,top and pathoffset) and set it to polyline.

***DEMO***

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
var points = [];
var random = fabric.util.getRandomInt;
points.push(new fabric.Point(random(100,200),random(200,300)));
points.push(new fabric.Point(random(200,300),random(100,200)));
points.push(new fabric.Point(random(200,250),random(150,200)));

var polyLine = new fabric.Polyline(points, {
 stroke: 'black',
 fill: ''
});
canvas.add(polyLine);
setPolyCoords();

function addPoint(){
 polyLine.points.push(new fabric.Point(random(100,400),random(100,400)));
 setPolyCoords();
}

function setPolyCoords(){
 polyLine._calcDimensions();
 polyLine.set({
  top : polyLine.minY,
  left : polyLine.minX,
  pathOffset : {
        x: polyLine.minX + polyLine.width / 2,
        y: polyLine.minY + polyLine.height / 2
      }
 });
 polyLine.dirty = true;
 polyLine.setCoords();
 canvas.renderAll();
}
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid #f00;
  margin: 0px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.22/fabric.js"></script>
<button onclick='addPoint()'>Add Point</button>
<canvas id="c" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

Comment: I found a sample code elsewhere and it was missing setting the dirty flag. Thanks for mentioning that here!

Answer (score 0):

With Fabric version 2.7.0 this is become easier then in @Durga his answer.
See the new code in the demo below.

You can also skip setting the `dirty` flag manually by passing `objectCaching: false` to your polyline during construction:

```
var polyLine = new fabric.Polyline(points, {
    stroke: 'black',
    fill: '',
    objectCaching: false
});
```

***DEMO***

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
var points = [];
var random = fabric.util.getRandomInt;
points.push(new fabric.Point(random(100,200),random(200,300)));
points.push(new fabric.Point(random(200,300),random(100,200)));
points.push(new fabric.Point(random(200,250),random(150,200)));

var polyLine = new fabric.Polyline(points, {
 stroke: 'black',
 fill: ''
});
canvas.add(polyLine);

function addPoint(){
 polyLine.points.push(new fabric.Point(random(100,400),random(100,400)));
 polyLine.dirty = true;
 canvas.renderAll();
}
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid #f00;
  margin: 0px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/fabricjs/fabric.js/master/dist/fabric.min.js"></script>
<button onclick='addPoint()'>Add Point</button>
<canvas id="c" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

Comment: This solution unfortunately doesn't recalculate the polyline's dimensions after adding new points, which means the bounding box and consequently the cache dimensions are incorrect post modification

Comment: @melchiar Thanks for your comment. I didn't expect that it has to be done manually after every change. Is there no convenience method on the Polyline class for calculating these things automatically? Something like `updateBoundingBox()` or `recalculateDimensions()`?

Comment: According to @andreabogazzi, this was not possible as of January 2018, however it is likely to change in future. https://github.com/fabricjs/fabric.js/issues/3488#issuecomment-356311531